# I used Bootstrap tour on my site. The tour works for the first time and then, it stops working. How do i resolve this error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

It works for the first time. So, i must have all my dependencies correct.
Here's my tour code.

```
var tour = new Tour({
    name: 'First Tour.'
    steps: [
    {
        element: "#no1",
        title: "NUMBER",
        content: "Enter the no. of codes needed."
    },
    {
        element: "#no2",
        title: "TYPE",
        content: "Enter the type needed."
    }
    ]
});

tour.init();
tour.start();
```

Comment: Try using `tour.start(true);` which will force start the tour. Refer [documentation](http://bootstraptour.com/api/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the data in your local storage to force restart. In Chrome -> Console -> Resources -> Local Storage -> YOUR_URL -> remove all keys related to the tour:
* tour_current_step
* tour_end